Does the throttling profile data for any STS missions exist?

I am working on a personal project that would need the first 100 seconds of data, but I am not sure where I can find this?

That information is available for every shuttle mission. It's in the post flight mission reports. You can find links to every post flight mission report here: https://spaceflight.training/library.htm1
Here's one I picked at random (STS-50).

1Full disclosure: It's my web page.

@ErickZaragoza If you find a report where they left out that information (the format changed over the years), leave a comment and I can probably dig it up for you.

question about the time column: how is it measured? I am guessing it is ddd:hh:mm:ss.sss but why 177 days? I would have guessed time for each mission would have been measured as an offset from some important moment, such as liftoff.

@VladimirCravero it's annoying, isn't it! It's GMT where 177 is the 177th day of the year.

Uhu - I guess it can be interesting to know on which day of the year the launch occurred, but I'm pretty sure this information is all over the place anyway. Any idea of why is is logged like this? Just adhering to a standard?
